# How to find the solutions of $x^3-x^2-x+1=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have to find the solutions of $x^3-x^2-x+1=0$. I know $x = 1$ but how to solve this? I'm lost on the step-by-step resolution.

Comment: Since you know x=1, is a solution, divide the equation by x-1 to get a quadric eqation, solve that to get another two solutions.

Comment: try to common (x-1)from expression

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT:

$$x^2(x-1)-1(x-1)=0\implies (x-1)(x^2-1)=0\implies (x-1)^2(x+1)=0$$

As the product is $0,$ at least one of the factors must be $0$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: $$x^3-x^2-x+1=x^2(x-1)-(x-1)$$ Keep the difference of squares formula in mind.